# How Do I create Logins for multiple users in C# console Program using filestream

Tags: c#

I have use this code to create a login for user, but if I try to add more, it would overwrite the present one. and i have try to use the append in the file mode, is giving me error message.

```
        public void AddNewUser()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Creating New User");
        String Username, Password = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter The UserName");
        Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter The Passwrod for the User");
        Password = Console.ReadLine();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("C:/Users/Olasunky/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TheFileVersionMaintenanceUtility/Password/UserNameAndPassword.txt"));
        sw.WriteLine(Username);
        sw.WriteLine(Password);
        sw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Done....");
    }
```

Comment: You can google for the `File IO Operations` that might solve your issue.If you just want to append the text. Or you can look at [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.IO.File.AppendText(string path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to append to the file instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you override the File on every execution.

`File.Create` - Creates a new File. If there is a File on the same path with the same Name and the same extension, it will delete the old one and create a new. 
Take a look at `File.AppendText` , this may help you solving the problem.

Also, in C# it is important to catch exceptions. It may give you an error message because there is no file or you are using File.AppendText wrong.

Answer (score 0):

true to append data to the file.false to overwrite the file. If the specified
 file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates
 a new file.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating New User");
            String Username, Password = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter The UserName");
            Username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter The Passwrod for the User");
            Password = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:/UserNameAndPassword.txt",true);
            sw.WriteLine(Username);
            sw.WriteLine(Password);
            sw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done....");
        }
```